# Find all prime fields

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

The question is stated as follow:

By a **prime field** we mean a field which contains no proprer subfield(that is, no subfield other than itself). Find all prime fields. (Hint: Use the characteristic.)

In the previous question in the book that Im following, I proved that if the characteristic of a field $\frak{F}$ is $p$, the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}_\frak{F}$ of the field, determines a subfield of $\frak{F}$ which is contained in everyother subfield of $\frak{F}$.

From this I suppose its possible to show that the prime of field of any finite field with chracteristic $p$ is isomorphic to eachother, but It still unclear to me if prime fields related to fields with characteristic $0$ or not being a prime all are isomorphic in some way.

Any tips will be appreciated, another related question is, Starting from a finite field with characteristic $n$ where $n$ is not a prime, how can I guarantee that the prime field related to this field have characteristic $m$ where $m$ is a prime?

Comment: There's a single prime field for characteristic $0$ as well. The characteristic of a field must be prime (or zero) else it would have zero divisors.

Comment: Upto isomorphism, the only prime fields are $\mathbb Q$ (if the characteristic is $0$) and $\mathbb Z_p$ (if the characteristic is the prime number $p$).

Comment: The book presents a simple example of field with 4 elements, but the characteristic is 2 which agree with you, but It make me very confuse. But reading your comment right now make me a bit less confuse, because I was just mixing cardinality with characteristic.

Comment: A finite field cannot have non-prime characteristic because a field is an integral domain. To find prime fields, note that any field contains $1$, so if it has characteristic $p$, it must contain a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is the only prime field of characteristic $p$ up to isomorphism. If a field has characteristic $0$, then it contains $\mathbb{Z}$ and therefore it contains its fraction field which is $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore $\mathbb{Q}$ is the only prime field of characteristic $0$.